# llenar ComboBox con enum c# en MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estoy usando MVC con C#,tengo un problema como puedo llenar un ComboBox con **@Html.DropDownList()** usando una enumeracion desde mi controlador, sabiendo que en mi ComboBox debe colocarse como value(numero en la enumeracion) y el texto(nombre del pais en la enumeracion)

```html
            <div class="text-left col-md-6">
                <label class="col-sm-12 control-label" for="email-03" style="font-weight: normal;padding-left: 0px;">País</label>

                <div class="text-left col-md-4" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                    @Html.DropDownList("DDLPais", ViewBag.Pais as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control col-md-12" })

                </div>
                <br />
            </div>
```

en el controlador

```html
public enum Pais
{
    Mexico = 1,
    EU = 2,
    Inglaterra = 3
}

List<Pais> lstStatus = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Pais)).ToList();

ViewBag.Pais = lstStatus;
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: @fredyfx creo que todo esta mal por que no funciona

Comment: Revisa en el sitio, ya he visto varias preguntas muy similares.

Comment: @LuisFernando Type 'Entidades.Paises' is not supported.
Nombre del parámetro: type', me marca ese error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para generar un dropdownlist desde un enum, será necesario que le asignes las propiedades del elemento.

```
var lstStatus = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Pais)).Cast<Pais>().ToList().Select(x => new DropDownList
    {
        Text = x.GetDescription(),
        Value = x.GetHashCode()
    })
    ViewBag.Pais = lstStatus;
```

Necesitas agregar la descripción a tu enum.

```
public enum Pais
{
    [DescriptionAttribute("Mexico ")]
    Mexico = 1,
    [DescriptionAttribute("EU ")]
    EU = 2,
    [DescriptionAttribute("Inglaterra ")]
    Inglaterra = 3
}
```

Comment: en la parte del Typeof() en TituloEnum debe ir el nombre de enumeracion y tambien en el cast()?, la enumeracion puede ir dentro de una clase ?, de esta forma bindeo ni enumeracion  @Html.DropDownList("Pais",
        (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Pais,
        "Select Pais")?

Comment: Error mío, ya actualice. Sí tienes un DTO para los dropdownlist se la puedes asignar sin problema.

Comment: Tengo este error 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'WhereSelectListIterator`2[Entidades.Paises+MuestraPais,<>f__AnonymousType14`1[System.Int32]]' al tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'.'

Comment: probablemente sea el modelo, despues del select new ahi agrega el modelo de dropdownlist.